# Can lightdm/gnome/compiz use bash instead of sh?

Tags: bash, shell, login, compiz

On my Ubuntu 12.04 logging in is handled by the `lightdm` which starts a `gnome-session` for the user which starts a `compiz` instance which then starts the applications the user clicks on.  Somewhere in this path the `.profile` file gets sourced, but whoever sources it, is doing it using `/bin/sh`, no matter what `/etc/passwd` states as the user's login shell.

This is problematic in my case.  I want to set a bash shell function on login time and export it; so I create a `~/.profile`:

```
l() {
  ls -la "$@"
}
export -f l
```

But this file now is not read by a `bash`, as I would expect when `/etc/passwd` states that my login shell is the `bash`.  No, instead it is read by an `sh` (which is linked to `dash` in my case) and which cannot handle the `export -f l` statement.

Is there a way to make `lightdm`/`gnome`/`compiz` honour my login shell as stated in `/etc/passwd` instead of using the `sh`?  Is there a configuration for this somewhere?

Comment: This could be an alias instead of a function and it could be set not in `.profile` but in `.bashrc`, and of course, in whatever rc file is used by `dash`. It's much more usual to declare these custom modifications whenever a shell is started, not just at login. In that case you also don't need export, as the function is instantiated when the shell starts. This will hopefully let you use your function without changing shells. As for whether you can tell `compiz` what shell to run, I don't know. I'd hope `$SHELL` variable would override it but I'll wait for a more qualified answer.

Comment: ① I intend to do a *lot* in this script file, so it should be done just once, not each time a new shell is started.  Creating shell functions is just one aspect.  ② Since I'm talking about the very initial login point, I have no chance to set `$SHELL` prior to this.  I would have expected that `$SHELL` would be filled with whatever is stated in `/etc/passwd`, but I guess that compiz just isn't using that variable but instead calls `sh` hard-wired.

Comment: Well... just start bash from dash and you are in.

Comment: Have you tried to create a `ln` from `sh` to `bash` rather than `dash`? That might be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @orion, no, this `.profile` is not an executable (i. e. not called as such), it is a configuration file which gets *sourced* by the caller (i. e. it is executed *by* the caller process) and is supposed to apply changes to the environment.  If I call a `bash` from within it, this creates a new process, and all environment changes this applies get lost when this `bash` terminates, leaving no changes on the environment of the caller.

Comment: @datUser, yes, that would solve the issue, but applying changes to the system always is a bit problematic (e. g. such a link might get overwritten on the next update of the package which installed the `dash`), so I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Is it really compiz that starts a login shell? I'm not on an Ubuntu/lightdm machine right now but IIRC lightdm starts `/etc/X11/Xsession` which loads `.profile` before considering your choice of session manager, and I don't see why compiz would start a login shell.

Comment: Right approach, @Gilles!  `lightdm` starts `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session` which is a plain `#!/bin/sh`-shell script which attempts to mimic the shell's login behaviour (including sourcing things like the `.profile`).  This is ugly as hell.  Whoever implemented this should be … pyunished (to quote Boss Nass).  My current workaround to solve this issue is to patch that script to use `/bin/bash` instead.  Works, but is prone to be overwritten with the next update of the package :-/

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you can override it immediately with `bash`. Your `.profile` could start with

```
read -r cmd rest < <(cat /proc/$$/cmdline | tr '\000' ' ')
if [ ! $(basename $(readlink -f $cmd)) = 'bash' ]; then
  exec /bin/bash "$rest"
fi

#... the rest of the .profile script
```

I believe it should work. Test it a little bit.

EDIT:

Previous version didn't work because `$0` is not the bash that runs the script but usually the name of the script, and `$@` doesn't include the name of the script that is running. This is why original commandline is obtained from `proc`, to actually reproduce the commandline completely, but with the first argument (the shell) replaced with bash, if it's not already `bash` (remove the `if` and you have an infinite recursion).

The clumsy reading is done because `proc` uses null character delimiters instead of spaces and thus makes our life a bit difficult. But no matter.

The parent shell is overwritten like agent smith overwrites people in the matrix. There is no more `dash`. The PID of `dash` and everything in it is taken over by `bash`. The new `bash` reruns the script (but this time gets to the end).

I recall that `.profile` is not passed as an argument to bash, but executed during initialization itself (sourced). You should review your particular situation carefully. Maybe it's better to actually force `exec /bin/bash --login` to avoid hassle with reading the command line. A login shell should then read `.profile` anyway.

The final proposal is therefore to simply put

```
if [ ! $(basename $(readlink -f $cmd)) = 'bash' ]; then
  exec /bin/bash --login
fi
```

into your `.profile` at the beginning and see what happens. Ideally this should make no difference if login shell is already bash, but should transparently override any other shell with bash with no notice by the user whatsoever.

Comment: Does this also stop `sh` reading the rest of the file?

Comment: `exec` essentially overwrites the process that called it. There is no more `dash` after that. The only trick here that apparently my solution above isn't exactly working because "$@" doesn't include the script name. Hang on. I'll fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is applicable here (the login/session setup chain varies a lot depending on the distribution, DM and session manager), but: `exec bash` will make the shell stop executing, but it's presumably executed from some session setup script, which will then be cut in the middle.

Comment: This is a really nice idea to replace the running shell.  Unfortunately this loses all the (source-)caller stack; nothing after the `exec` gets evaluated, whatever script sources *us* is not going to continue after the `source` statement.  Restarting the script completely is a weak attempt to work around that which in my case does not solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: It's worth trying... the `.profile` should be sourced only by the outermost login shell and `exec`-ing bash as a new login shell *will* terminate `.profile` sourcing... but the new bash will source it again because it is a login shell. So hopefully, the login shell started by the display manager should be fine.

Comment: If the startup chain calls the login shell with any nonstandard parameters and extra scripts, it should show up in the `cmdline`. And it can't be a pipe because a login shell must survive connected to the terminal.

Comment: BTW: Rather than trying to find the stuff in proc, why not just check `$BASH_VERSION` to see if its bash?